# Powershell Salesforce SOAP API SessionHeader Type Converion Issue

Tags: api, powershell, soap, salesforce

Hi I am having trouble setting the SessionHeaderValue. I am basing my code on c#.Net. The login works and I receive the serviceUrl and sessionId in the login result but I can't get the session Id set in the session header

Here is the code

```
$uri = "c:\installs\sforce.wsdl"
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
# Proxy
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace sforce -UseDefaultCredential
# Login
$loginResult = $service.login($username, $password)
$service.Url = $loginResult.serverUrl
$service.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object sforce.SessionHeader
```

This is the error I get which is a bit odd.

Exception setting "SessionHeaderValue": "Cannot convert the "sforce.SessionHeader" value of type "sforce.SessionHeader" to type "sforce.SessionHeader"."

I have been playing with this for a few hours now and have run out of ideas.

Any help is appreciated.

Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is that you can't reuse `$service`.  Your instance of `$service` is only good for the login, and that's it.  I think it's due to the way New-WebServiceProxy works.  Check this little script out:

```
$uri = 'file://C:\projects\CRM\SalesForce\Integration\enterprise.xml'
$api = new-webserviceproxy -uri $uri -NameSpace SalesForce

$api.GetType().Module.Assembly.ManifestModule.ScopeName

$api = new-object SalesForce.SforceService.ScopeName
$api.GetType().Module.Assembly.ManifestModule
```

If you were to run this script, (of course you'd need to substitute your own WSDL), you'd see something like this (the DLLs are dynamic, so the names will be different):

```
mhgl0l5w.dll 
vzecopaq.dll
```

Notice that not only are the object references for $api different, but the dynamic assembly that New-WebServiceProxy creates is different for each one, which isn't what you might expect.  That's why your cast is failing; your objects with the same name are different because they come from different dynamic assemblies.   I'm not sure why the behavior is this way - if it's a peculiarity of New-WebServiceProxy, or somehow in SalesForce's WSDL.

The solution is actually pretty simple.  Recreate your service object off the namespace generated by New-WebServiceProxy like so:

```
$uri = "c:\installs\sforce.wsdl"
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
# Proxy
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace sforce -UseDefaultCredential

# Login
$loginResult = $service.login($username, $password)

$service = New-Object sforce.SforceService
$service.Url = $loginResult.serverUrl
$service.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object sforce.SessionHeader
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. This worked! I can finally query salesforce from powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [webpage](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2126088) that implies the the `$service.SessionHeaderValue` instance should be created using something like:

```
$service.SessionHeaderValue = New-ObjectFromProxy -proxy $service -proxyAttributeName "SessionHeaderValue" -typeName "SessionHeader"
```

There was a definition for the New-ObjectFromProxy function in [PowerShell + SOAP + AuthenticationInfoValue](https://communities.bmc.com/thread/65122):

```
function New-ObjectFromProxy {
    param($proxy, $proxyAttributeName, $typeName)

    # Locate the assembly for $proxy
    $attribute = $proxy | gm | where { $_.Name -eq $proxyAttributeName }
    $str = "`$assembly = [" + $attribute.TypeName + "].assembly"
    invoke-expression $str

    # Instantiate an AuthenticationHeaderValue object.
    $type = $assembly.getTypes() | where { $_.Name -eq $typeName }

    return $assembly.CreateInstance($type)
}
```

I don't profess to be a powershell expert, but it appears the instance of the object that New-Object creates isn't really the same type that the proxy object is expecting. Confusingly, they do have the same name.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have just tried this and I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that you cannot define a web service proxy twice for the same namespace.  This is required for a flow where you need to go to SOAP API to login, then pass the session id to the metadata API to make your requests.

Compare:

```
    $LoginResponse = $sf.login($username, $password)
    $newSession = $LoginResponse.sessionId
    $newURL = $LoginResponse.serverUrl
    $service = New-Object sforce.SforceService
    $service.Url = $LoginResponse.serverUrl
    $service.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object sforce.SessionHeader
    $service.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = $LoginResponse.sessionId

    # Set the batch size to 2000
    # Though, if it contains two long text area fields, it will set it as 200
    # This is to avoid long SOAP messages and is controlled by SF
    $service.QueryOptionsValue = new-Object sforce.QueryOptions
    $service.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize = 2000
    $service.QueryOptionsValue.batchSizeSpecified = $true


    $mdservice= new-WebServiceProxy -URI $mdwsdl -Namespace sforce
    $mdservice = New-Object sforce.MetadataService
    $mdservice.Url = $LoginResponse.metadataServerUrl
    $mdservice.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object sforce.SessionHeader
    $mdservice.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = $LoginResponse.sessionId
```

This will generate the following error:

```
"sforce.SessionHeader" to type "sforce.SessionHeader"."
At line:22 char:5
+     $mdservice.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object sforce.SessionHeader
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

The property 'sessionId' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:23 char:5
+     $mdservice.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = $LoginResponse.sessionI ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Whereas the below code will not error:

```
    $sf = new-WebServiceProxy -URI $pwsdl -Namespace sforce
    $LoginResponse = $sf.login($username, $password)
    $newSession = $LoginResponse.sessionId
    $newURL = $LoginResponse.serverUrl
    $service = New-Object sforce.SforceService
    $service.Url = $LoginResponse.serverUrl
    $service.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object sforce.SessionHeader
    $service.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = $LoginResponse.sessionId

    # Set the batch size to 2000
    # Though, if it contains two long text area fields, it will set it as 200
    # This is to avoid long SOAP messages and is controlled by SF
    $service.QueryOptionsValue = new-Object sforce.QueryOptions
    $service.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize = 2000
    $service.QueryOptionsValue.batchSizeSpecified = $true


    $mdservice= new-WebServiceProxy -URI $mdwsdl #Don't set namespace here
    # Notice that we are getting the namespace dynamically
    $type = $mdservice.GetType().NameSpace
    $mdservice = New-Object ($type + '.MetadataService')
    $mdservice.Url = $LoginResponse.metadataServerUrl
    $mdservice.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object ($type + '.SessionHeader')
    $mdservice.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = $LoginResponse.sessionId
```

Answer (score -1):

Exception setting "SessionHeaderValue": "Cannot convert the "sforce.SessionHeader" value of type "sforce.SessionHeader" to type "sforce.SessionHeader"."

```
$service.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object sforce.SessionHeader
```

After New-Object you have to specify the correct class name. Try this:

```
#Login to Salesforce
$loginResults = $service.login($username,$password)

#set the session Id in partner Object 
$service.Url = $loginResults.serverUrl
$sessionHeaderObjClassName = ($service.GetType().FullName) -replace "SforceService","SessionHeader"
$service.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object $sessionHeaderObjClassName
$service.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = $loginResults.sessionId
```