# SF API QueryResult throws error

Tags: soap, salesforce

need help with an issue. Here is the java code sample.

```apex
String soqlQuery = "SELECT Id FROM ...."; 
QueryResult qResult = connection.query(soqlQuery);
```

This throws up the following exception:

> Incompatible type 'class com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult' specified as xsi:type. It must be a subclass of 'class com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult'

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may be having a similar issue to myself although I was using powershell. See Dave Markle's answer to my question here: [Powershell Salesforce SOAP API SessionHeader Type Converion Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043774/powershell-salesforce-soap-api-sessionheader-type-converion-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Strange, this issue got resolved automatically when I restarted the server app.  Must be something to do with container and caching.